# How to *return* Binary of decimal in recursion code Python

Tags: python, recursion, binary

Learning Recursion. I was able to write Python code to *print* binary number using recursion but couldn't figure out how to *return* this binary number. I am only getting the first mod value when I return, probably because, as I understand, the stack folds back to the beginning by the time it can return. (Hope this is not wrong). I would greatly appreciate if you could not only provide your answer to get the function to return the result but also explain how it works.

def binary(n):

```
if n == 0:
    return
else:
   binary (n//2)       
   print (n%2,end="")
```

binary(233)

Thank you

Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *return* a value, you need to use `return` instead of `print`.

But also pay attention to this:

- When using `return` you need to accumulate the binary digits in a string
- The base case is not correct: 0 does not translate to an empty string when that is the original value of `n` (then you want to get 0 back). It only should be an empty string if you are in a recursive call. The way to solve this, is to stop the recursion one step earlier, i.e. when `n < 2`.

Here is how that works out:

```
def binary(n):
    if n < 2:
        return str(n)
    else:
        return binary(n // 2) + str(n % 2)
```

Call as:

```
print(binary(13))
```

Comment: This is working perfectly fine,thanks trincot.

Comment: Thank you. so much Trincot. Also I see that return value of  binary(n // 2) + str(n % 2) is not the same as str(n%2)+binary (n//2).  How did you automatically use the right order? I am trying to understand how to *think* in the way recursion works. Hope you can help teaching how you thought the answer through.. I am trying hard to get this recursion concept right

Comment: When you have a given `n`, then the *rightmost* binary digit will be `n%2`. All other digits have to come to the left of it, and are generated by the recursive call. This is why the recursive call comes at the left of the `+` and `str(n%2)` at the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def binary(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        i = n % 2
        print(i, end="")
        return binary(n // 2) + str(i)

x = binary(233)
print()  # seperate the print's in binary from this print
print(x)
```

To actually return something from the function you need to put something into the `return` statement. Here for each call of `binary(n)` i'm returning the number obtained by your operation as a string so I can concatenate it together and return it at the end.

Comment: I think it's not a correct solution